# Extracing metadata from URL using Firebase as backend

Tags: html, angular, firebase, metadata

Is there anyway to extract Metadata such as Title, description and image from URL using Firebase? I can do it easily on dotnet using MetaScraper but i'm not sure how i can achieve this if i use Firebase as backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase backend, you can just use node modules. For example this one: [fetch-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-meta-tags)

In your firebase backend you can add dependencies, as can be read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies)